# Modify data in a text file

Tags: java, android, file-io, text-files, edit

Have created a file that stores records with data separated by "," and ending with ";".

So far I have been able to append to the file, but now **I need to update specific elements in a record**. Each record starts with a unique identifier.

Below is a sample of how the file is opened and each unique ID is read into an array:

```
DataInputStream fin = new DataInputStream(openFileInput("Updates.txt"));
try {
    for (;;) {
    String record = fin.readUTF();
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Record "+record);
    elements = record.split(",");
    String trackingNo = elements[0];
    UpdateRecord item = new UpdateRecord(trackingNo);
    }
}
catch (EOFException e) {
    Log.i("Data Input Sample", "End of file reached");
}
fin.close();
```

Comment: If you are working with text files and need to modify something in the middle of it, you will have to regenerate all content afterwards.

Comment: It seems to me that using a database would make life much easier.

Comment: Hoping to avoid using a database with this version of the application.

Comment: Hoping to avoid using a database with this version of the application, keeping resources at a minimum. Preferences is an option as well. So is there no way to update bytes in the file without regenerating the file?

Comment: @Butch : The easiest way is going to be read line by line and write each line out to a temp file. When you come to the line you want to modify, make the changes and write it out to the temp file, then read the rest of the lines and write them out to the temp file. Close both files, delete the original then rename the temp file to have the original's name.

Comment: Thank you All, will give MisterSquonk response a try. Have a great weekend.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub example1()
Dim strFinal As String
Dim strline As String

Open "D:\textfile.txt" For Input As #1
    While EOF(1) = False
        Line Input #1, strline
        If Len(strline) > 24 Then
            strFinal = strFinal + ModifyColumn(strline)
            Else
            strFinal = strFinal + strline + vbCrLf
        End If
    Wend
    strFinal = strFinal
Close #1

Open "D:\textfile.txt" For Output As #1
    Print #1, strFinal
Close #1
End Sub


Function ModifyColumn(ByVal strInput As String) As String
    Dim arrString() As String
    Dim strOutput As String
    'split the columns
    arrString = Split(strInput, vbTab)
    'concatenate the first 2 column as they are
    strOutput = arrString(0) + vbTab + arrString(1) + vbTab + arrString(2)
    'add 100$ to column3
    requirevalue = Left(arrString(3), InStr(1, arrString(3), "|") - 1)
    last3Digit = Right(requirevalue, 3)
    If Left(requirevalue, 3) = "max" Then
        Newvalue = vbTab + "OTPxxxxxx" & last3Digit & "|" & Right(arrString(3), Len(arrString(3)) - InStr(1, arrString(3), "|")) + vbCrLf
    Else
        Newvalue = vbTab + arrString(3) + vbCrLf
    End If
    strOutput = strOutput & Newvalue
    'strOutput = strOutput + Strings.Trim(Str(CDbl(Left(arrString(3), Len(arrString(2)) - 1)) + 100)) + "$" + vbCrLf
    ModifyColumn = strOutput
End Function`enter code here`
```